# How to show first 6 items in vuejs with v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have object, what have 17 items.

```
.div(v-for='item in section')
```

But i need to show only fight 6 items in first block, and all another in second. How i can do that?

Comment: `slice`-array? computed properties? methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a computed property:

```
computed: {

    showFirstSix: function()
        { 
           return this.section.slice(0,6)
           }
   }
```

then iterate through it

```
 .div(v-for='item in showFirstSix')
```